# PHP Captcha showing error message even when captcha is enter correctly

Tags: php, html

I have created a contact form that once the user enters their details and clicks submit the details they have entered are  sent to my email. The form works well and the emails are being sent, however I noticed that I would receive a lot of spam emails from the contact form. I decided that the best way to stop the the spam would be to add a captcha so that the user must enter the letters within the captcha image before the form can be submitted.

I have been able to get the captcha image to display, however even if the captcha is not entered correctly the form still seems to submit.

Here is my contact form code

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $captcha = $_POST['captcha-input'];

    $from= 'From:' . $name .  "\r\n" .'Reply-To:' . $email . "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $to = 'example@yahoo.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from example.com';
    $body = "$message";

    
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
      $errorName = 'Please enter your name';
    }
    
  
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $errorEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }
    
    
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
      $errorMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }

    if (!$_POST['captcha-input'] || filter_var($_POST['captcha-input'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) {
      $errorCaptcha = 'Please enter the captcha';
     } 
    
    if ($_SESSION['CAPTCHA_CODE'] !== $captchaUser) {
      $result = '<div id="error" class="error">CAPTCHA has failed</div>';
  } else if (!$errorName && !$errorEmail && !$errorMessage) {
     if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
         $result='<div id="success" class="success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
       } else {
         $result='<div class="error">Sorry there was an error sending your message. </div>';
       }
       $_POST = array();
   }
  }
```

Comment: `$captchaUser` should be `$captcha` or vice versa I guess.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see is, you have an mistake in your variable name. In this line:

```
$captcha = $_POST['captcha-input'];
```

You were reading the captcha entered by the user to the `$captcha` variable.

But here:

```
if ($_SESSION['CAPTCHA_CODE'] !== $captchaUser) {
```

You are using the wrong variable name for comparison!

It should be this:

```
if ($_SESSION['CAPTCHA_CODE'] !== $captcha) {
```

---

**EDIT**

I am assuming that, you are setting the catpcha after that main IF condition (before the display takes place) :

```
<?php

  // for session
  session_start();

  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      //... all your code goes here..
  }

  // generate the captcha code and store it in session
  $_SESSION['CAPTCHA_CODE'] = 'new_captcha_code_generated';
```

Also, one more thing I noticed that, you are not calling the `session_start()` function. Please make sure that you call this function at the very start of your PHP code, in all pages. Then only the SESSION would work properly! Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: sadly this doesn't seem to be the problem, I'm really confused as to what it could be

Comment: the session_start() is in the file that generates the captcha image, I will add it to my question

Comment: you were right I needed the session_start() in both files

Comment: @becky Glad to know that you got it resolved! If my answer helped you in resolving the issue, can you please award the bounty points (that you were offering) to my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a variable that is never initialised, in the line:

```
if ($_SESSION['CAPTCHA_CODE'] !== $captchaUser)
```

You're using the `$captchaUser` variable which is never created, perhaps you mean the `$captcha` variable you initialise toward the top of your page?

Comment: its initialised in th file that generates the captcha image